# Rails Association Callbacks are not running when creating records in another way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

This is my `User` model and its `Subscription`:

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions, :before_add => :cancel_subscriptions!

  def cancel_subscriptions!(new_subscription=nil)
    subscriptions.each(&:cancel!)
  end
end

# app/models/subscription.rb
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

so, when I do `some_user.subscriptions.create`, it executes the `:cancel_subscriptions!` callback and then I'm happy. But then I do `Subscription.create :user => some_user` the callback doesn't seem to being called and I get sad, so very, very sad.

Is there a way to get sure the callback executes whenever a `Subscription` associated to a `User` is created?

**PD:** I'd really like not having to write a `:before_create` in my `Subscription` model, because I think cancelling all subscriptions should be `User` model's responsibility.

Comment: If the user is running the show (which is reasonable), then does `Subscription.create :user => some_user` make sense? The code on its own makes sense but maybe not from an API perspective, if User runs the show then User should run the whole show.

Comment: I totally agree, @mu! Actually, I use `some_user.subscriptions.create` everytime. This is more of a paranoic/technical-curiosity question.

Comment: I think `:before_add` is attached to the collection but the collection isn't smart enough to know about things that happen behind its back.

Comment: I understand. Thank you. Do you think I should close the question?

Comment: I'd leave it open for a bit longer, it is morning somewhere so new people are coming online.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, there's `:inverse_of` option for `belongs_to` that should handle this situation. Specifically, let the other side of association know about changes on this side. But this only works if the other side is `has_one`. It's not clear from documentation but you can [see it the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.8/activerecord/lib/active_record/associations/belongs_to_association.rb#L59-60).

So as of now there's no way to make it work automatically.

A note on PD: you really want to move subscription functionality off User model. Managing subscriptions in User model increases coupling. And as you have Subscription model anyway make it do it's job and manage subscriptions on a single user. Also `before_add` is not a good place to manage subscriptions anyway. You're performing destructive action in a hook_that runs before any resource have been saved. That is, you can cancel all subscriptions and that your new subscription fails a validation. Thus, you've lost your old subscription (you don't know which one was active before) and you have invalid new one that can not be saved.